# Could not find the pytorch 1.9.1 in conda's current channels

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda

I create a new conda virtual environment and try to install the pytorch 1.9.1 by using conda install pytorch=1.9.1. But, conda reports the PackageNotFoundError as follows.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- pytorch==1.9.1

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/python/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/python/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  Help！！！ Thanks

Comment: I have fixed the problem with pip, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The right commands are listed on the pytorch web site. They should use the `pytorch` channel, e.g. with cuda:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```